# jQuery resize of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-effects

I have managed to fit automatically the images of the gallery per row depending if it´s horizontal (one image per row) or vertical (two images per row).

The problem now is that I want the images to be scalable (resize on window resize) but I have no idea how to achieve it. How it should me made? **(I'm looking for a javascript/jquery solution to avoid height: auto problems...)**

This is the web: http://ldlocal.web44.net/test2/gallery.html

Can be downloaded here: http://ldlocal.web44.net/test2/test.zip

this is my code:

```
var gallery = new Gallery($('#gallery_images_inner'));

function Gallery(selector){

this.add_module = function(type, image){
    var container = $('<div />' , {
        'class' : 'gallery_container'
    }).append(image);
    if(type == 'horizontal'){
        var h_ar = image.attr('height') / image.attr('width');
        container.css({
            'width' : selector.width(),
            'height' : selector.width()*h_ar
        })
    }
    if(type == 'vertical'){
        container.css({
            'width' : v_width,
            'height' : v_height
        })
    }
    container.appendTo(selector);
    container.children('img').fitToBox();
}
var _this = this;
var gutter = 0;
// start vars for counting on vertical images
var v_counter = 0;
var w_pxls = 0;
var h_pxls = 0;
// iterates through images looking for verticals
selector.children('img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('width') < $(this).attr('height')){
        v_counter++;
        h_pxls += $(this).attr('height');
        w_pxls += $(this).attr('width');
    }
})
// calculates average ar for vertical images (anything outside from aspect ratio will be croped)
var h_avrg = Math.floor(h_pxls/v_counter);
var w_avrg = Math.floor(w_pxls/v_counter);
var v_ar = h_avrg/w_avrg;
var v_width = (selector.width())/2;
var v_height = v_width*v_ar;
selector.children('img').each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).attr('width')) > parseInt($(this).attr('height'))){
        _this.add_module('horizontal', $(this));
    }else{
        _this.add_module('vertical', $(this));
    }
})
selector.isotope({
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: selector.width() / 2
    }
});

}
```

Comment: You have posted the same question 4 times in 5 hours.. that is not the way to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

Update ALL NEW CODE:

http://jsfiddle.net/vYGGN/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <img class="fluidimage" src="http://thedoghousediaries.com/comics/uncategorized/2011-04-06-1b32832.png"
    />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        body {
            text-align:center;
        }
        img {
            float: right;
            margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
        }
        #content {
            width:70%;
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function imageresize() {
                var contentwidth = $('#content').width();
                if ((contentwidth) < '300') {
                    $('.fluidimage').attr('height', '300px');
                } else {
                    $('.fluidimage').attr('height', '600px');
                }
            }

            imageresize(); //Triggers when document first loads      

            $(window).bind("resize", function () { //Adjusts image when browser resized  
                imageresize();
            });

        });
```

Found this at this article:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/quick-tip-resizing-images-based-on-browser-window-size/

Comment: I have put a number on newValue but it doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: yeah, now I applied it to the class of the image and now the image distorts on the first resize, no more resize after that and it lost it's aspect ratio :(... I have the jQuery library loaded :)

Comment: I used the updated code but now it doesn't even resizes... sorry

Comment: @fxg Found an article and just did one from complete scratch with a jsFiddle. If you trace the code you should be able to edit it to make it work with your code.

Comment: thanks for the research, but this is doesn't make a smooth resize, also it won't work with the code when there are two images pero row. Thank you very much! but I'll keep looking for something

Comment: Well I wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize images automatically and scale them down proportionally, all you have to do is set a css `max-width` on the `<img>` tag.  You can scale it down automatically with a percentage value according to the `$(window)` or any element in the document.  Here's an example of how to scale it proportionally using the `$(window)` to a percentage of the window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var xWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.[img class]').each(function() {
            $(this).css({maxWidth: xWidth * ([your percentage value of window] / 100)});
        });
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Change `[img class]` to the class of the images.
Change `[your percentage value of window]` to the percent of the window element you want your images width to be scaled at.  So, if you want 90%, change this to 90.  When the user resizes the browser window, it will automatically resize the images accordingly as well.

Comment: I tried with the class of the images but it doesn't do anything on the window resize, thanks anyway

Comment: Did you set a percentage value of the window in `[your percentage value of window]` that the images will be using?  It should automatically resize the image to the percent of the window when you resize the browser window down.  Are you saying that this does not work?

Comment: yeah, I set the percentage as you said to 90, but it stays static

Comment: Ok, updated my answer, please use `$(window).resize()` as in the answer.  That should do it.

Comment: I put the new code in the the class and the %, still the same, no console errors but no resize also :( it just doesn't do anything :(

Comment: It's not within the function, right?  Should be taken out of the function.

Comment: still the same hehe :( oh, it just doesn't make anything...

Comment: I think something is blocking it from working, trying using `'width'` instead of `maxWidth`

Comment: nope, still the same, here is the file if you want to check, i really need help please http://ldlocal.web44.net/test2/test.zip

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer even moreso now, should definitely work now!  Place the following code outside of the function, and make changes to it accordingly.

Comment: still the same, nothing happens mm. Yeah the code it's outside the function with the changes you said

Comment: I think i'm going to put the question again if someone know a way, thank you, i give you +1 on the answer for the help!

Comment: Strange, I am testing this and have no problems with this code, works as is.  If you have widths/heights assigned to your `<img>` tags, remove them, and try this code again.

Comment: In any case, good luck!